# Asp.Net page does not respond until cookies are deleted

Tags: asp.net, azure, memcached, azure-virtual-machine

We have deployed our Asp.Net webforms app on Azure platform, the app is being served by two web servers load balanced. Asp.Net session is managed by memcashed.

Generally app works fine but randomly it gets hanged, if we try to reload the app, request is not getting processed by the browser, no error at all, continuous loading.

Only way to make the app work again is by DELETING COOKIES for this specific app from the browser. 
This happens in Firefox as well as in Chrome so does not seem to be a browser specific issue. 
Cookies in particular is not that heavy, there are only 3 cookies, 1 being asp.net session cookie and two other for persisting user credentials.

App is about real-time chat service so it polls web server at each 4 seconds.

We have already referred one [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6468398/asp-net-webforms-app-sometimes-fails-to-load-until-cookies-deleted) but that does not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it happens randomly it looks like it caused by load balanced configuration. From my experience the most common reason for issues with load balanced farm - different **machineKey** values.

Try to check you have the same **machineKey** value in [web.config for both servers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649308.aspx#paght000007_webfarmdeploymentconsiderations).

Comment: i have checked , Machine key is same for both machine.

Comment: OK then, another guess. You mentioned you use memcashed for managing ASP.Net Session. [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/290966/is-memcached-interchangeable-with-asp-net-state-server) says that it doesn't support data mirroring. So maybe when app hangs you switched to another load balanced machine that doesn't have needed Session values? And in this case when you remove cookie you force application to create new Session and it works fine again.

Comment: Yes, I am aware about this, we are using same end points on both web servers, that ensures that same cache is available at both the places.